# Perforce eclipse plugin not setting files writeable

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I am currently struggling with getting the Perforce plugin to work properly in eclipse. Despite the fact that I have checked out a file I cannot actually edit it (typing has no effect) - the file seems to stay read-only.

When I try to edit a file that isn't checked out the perforce plugin does check it out automatically - however I still can't actually edit it. Restarting eclipse doesn't help. I've tried this with both eclipse Kepler and Luna, with identical results.

Right-click->properties on a file in the project explorer and setting the write bits there doesn't work - once I click 'Apply' or 'OK' the bits immediately revert to not being set.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve it by:

- removing my source tree from disk and forcing a full resync in perforce
- and clearing elipse's workspace and reimporting all projects, associating the perforce plugin with them, etc.

Doing just one or the other (clearing eclipse's workspace or deleting the source tree and resyncing it) did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling the 'allwrite' option in your Perforce workspace? See the following instructions:

```
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Eclipse-plugin-automatic-checkout-on-edit
```

Hope this helps.

REFERENCES

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Eclipse-plugin-How-to-configure-automatic-checkout-on-save

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I tried enabling 'allwrite', unfortunately without success. Files remain unchangeable (I've restarted eclipse after the change as well, just to make sure).